# Convert a data frame to a dictionary with a few keys (member_IDs) and additive values (account balances)

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, dictionary, type-conversion

I have following problem:
My goal is to extract the unique member IDs of a data frame and have the as keys and also extract and sum up the transactions they have and have them as values.

*unique mem_id = e.g. 70850441974905670928446*

*amount = 150.78*

*card_members = df['unique_mem_id'].unique()*

EDIT:
Here an excerpt from the dataframe:

```
transaction_date    unique_mem_id   description amount
6/21/2014   7.08504E+22 HILLERS MARKET         NORTHVILLE   MI  61.72
6/22/2014   7.08504E+22 BUSCH'S #1032          PLYMOUTH     MI  25.48
6/23/2014   7.08504E+22 SPEEDWAY XXXXX 5 M     PLYMOUTH     MI  30.73
6/23/2014   7.08504E+22 HENDERSON GLASS INC    NOVI         MI  29.95
6/23/2014   7.08504E+22 HILLERS MARKET         NORTHVILLE   MI  59.6
6/23/2014   7.08504E+22 SPEEDWAY XXXXX 5 M     PLYMOUTH     MI  60.59
6/24/2014   7.08504E+22 BEACHWAY RESORT        SAUGATUCK    MI  1142.4
6/24/2014   7.08504E+22 PUMPERNICKELS EATERY   SAUGATUCK    MI  88.52
6/24/2014   7.08504E+22 DEMOND'S SUPER         DOUGLAS      MI  79.75
6/25/2014   7.08504E+22 DEMOND'S SUPER         DOUGLAS      MI  128.21
```

EDIT END

> DatetimeIndex: 852 entries, 2014-06-21 to 2020-01-23 Data columns
>   (total 4 columns):  #   Column            Non-Null Count  Dtype
>
> ---  ------            --------------  -----
>   0   transaction_date  852 non-null    datetime64[ns]
>   1   unique_mem_id   852 non-null    object
>   2   description       852 non-null   object
>   3   amount            852 non-null    float64
>   dtypes: datetime64ns, float64(1), object(2) memory usage: 53.3+ KB

This is the dictionary I tried to code:

```
#test for transactions
from collections import defaultdict
transaction_dict = defaultdict(list)

for row in df_card.items():
    try:
        key = card_members
        value = df_card.amount
    except ValueError:
        continue

    transaction_dict[key] += value

print(transaction_dict)
```

THe error that comes up is: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

I have also tried df_card.iterrows() but that also fails :(

Comment: Provide some example data.

Comment: You seem to have just 3 columns but each row in your data contains 6 attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `df_card.iterrows` as follow:

```
transaction_dict = {}
for i, row in df_card.iterrows():
  key = row['unique_mem_id']
  val = row['amount']
  transaction_dict[key] = transaction_dict.get(key,0) + val
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried this and it worked with minor adaptions. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

```py
dic = {}
for i in range(len(df)):
    key = df.at[i, 'unique_mem_id']
    if df.at[i, 'unique_mem_id'] in dic:
        dic[key] += df.at[i, 'description amount']
    else:
        dic[key] = df.at[i, 'description amount']
```

Try this !
First we create a dictionary. Then we traverse each row of the dataframe and check if the particular `unique_mem_id` is already present as a key in the dictionary. If it's a key, just add the `description_amount` to that key, else create a new key in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

To have this completed and useful for 3rd parties here my final solution:
I used a work-around that was a sideproduct of following steps but will be similar to the solutions Yosua posted.

1. create a new column that is either marking transactions as "expense" or "income" and then run an if loop until it hits the first "income" and add that up.

´

```
transaction_class_card = pd.Series([], dtype = 'object')
    for index, i in enumerate(df_card['transaction_category_name']):
        if i in card_inc:
            transaction_class_card[index] = "income"
        elif i in card_exp:
            transaction_class_card[index] = "expense"
        else:
            transaction_class_card[index] = "NOT_CLASSIFIED"
    df_card.insert(loc = len(df_card.columns), column = "transaction_class", value = transaction_class_card)
```

´

After the new column is appended, I use following to iterate over the rows as tuples and stop as soon as I hit "income", all "expenses" before are then added up.

Slicing of the dataframe

```
df_1 = df_card[['unique_mem_id', 'amount', 'transaction_class']][df_card['unique_mem_id'] == '70850441974905670928446']
```

Iteration with tuples

```
cumulative_amount = []
amount_list = []
for row in df_1.itertuples():
   #access data using column names
   if row.transaction_class == "expense":
     #print(index, row.unique_mem_id, row.amount, row.transaction_class)
     amount_list.append(row.amount)
     cumulative_amount = np.cumsum(amount_list, axis = 0)
     #print(row.unique_mem_id, cumulative_amount)
   else:
  #print(f"stopped at user_ID: {row.unique_mem_id}, cumulative sum injected {cumulative_amount[-1]}")
                        break
                #print out the member id as part of the for-loop and and the last element of the list which is the amount to be injected
                print(f"unique_member_ID: {row.unique_mem_id}; initial injection needed in USD: {cumulative_amount[-1]}")
```

That prints the respective member_ID and the sum of their expenses.
Hope these variants help :)